# SQL returning 0 for count(), but returning multiple rows with simple SELECT

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Sorry if the phrasing of my question was not very clear.

I am running this simple query below

```
SELECT count(cg)
FROM all_data
WHERE cg is null
```

and am getting 0 as the result. When I run this query

```
SELECT cg
FROM all_data
WHERE cg is null
```

and get a bunch of records that fit the criteria. There are very obviously many records that have a `cg` value of null, but they do not appear from the `count()` query.

Is there a reason for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is there any other behaviour if you replace `count(cg)` by `count(*)` ?

Comment: count() only counts non-null values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aggregates (`COUNT()`, `SUM()` etc.) ignore NULL values.

Use `COUNT(*)` to count all rows matching your condition.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM all_data
 WHERE cg IS NULL
```

Further reading - [Count Function (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177890(v=office.12).aspx):

> The Count function does not count records that have Null fields unless expr is the asterisk (*) wildcard character. If you use an asterisk, Count calculates the total number of records, including those that contain Null fields. Count(*) is considerably faster than Count([Column Name]).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the amount of null values use the following query

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN CG IS NULL THEN 1 END) AMOUNT_CG
FROM all_data
```

No more follow the tip of the friend above

Comment: This approach requires a full table scan every time regardless of how many null values are in the table and therefore is inappropriate in majority of cases

Answer (score 0):

According to the SQL Reference Manual section on [Aggregate Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm):

All aggregate functions except COUNT(*) and GROUPING ignore nulls. You can use the NVL function in the argument to an aggregate function to substitute a value for a null. COUNT never returns null, but returns either a number or zero. For all the remaining aggregate functions, if the data set contains no rows, or contains only rows with nulls as arguments to the aggregate function, then the function returns null.

> So from above information we can conclude that to solve your problem use `count(*)` instead of `count(cg)`.